# Querying by meta key and value

Tags: meta-query

I have a custom post type which has an array as a meta data.
Here's how it looks inside `wp_postmeta` table.

- meta_key: _allowed_companies
- meta_value: a:2:{i:0;s:3:"275";i:1;s:4:"8386";}

Obviously, this `_allowed_companies` meta is an array with two values of `275` and `8386`, each representing a post ID of a company.

On front-end, I wish to display a list of items filtered by the allowed company. Say, in a form, if I choose company `275` and click submit, then all the items which has `275` inside `its _allowed_companies` meta will be displayed.

This is what I tried but in vain:
(Below code uses two query conditions of `_item_type` and `_item_allowed_companies`. `_item_type` is a plain string and works fine, but the problem kid is `_item_allowed_companies`.)

```
$item_type = 'Assets';
$allowed_company = 275;

$meta_array = array();
$meta_array = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
if( $item_type ) $meta_array[] = array( 'key' => '_item_type', 'value' => $item_type, 'compare' => '=' );
if( $allowed_company ) $meta_array[] = array( 'key' => '_item_allowed_companies', 'value' => $allowed_company, 'compare' => 'IN' );

$args = array( 
  'post_type'       => 'item',
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  => $posts_per_page,
  'paged'           => $paged,
  'meta_query'      => $meta_array
);
```

I think the use of `compare` operator of `IN` is wrong here, but have no idea how to alter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `REGEXP` operator in `META_COMPARE`.

For example:

```
$meta_array[] = array( 
    'key' => '_item_allowed_companies', 
    'value' => $allowed_company, 
    'compare' => 'REGEXP' 
);

$args = array( 
    'post_type'         => 'item',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_query'        => $meta_array
);
```

References:

- [`WP_Query` Custom Field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)
- [Trac ticket #18736](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18736)

Comment: This is great and works like a charm! Yeah, I saw 'REGEXP' operator in wordpress codex, but had no idea what that means and didn't try that one. So cool. Thank you, Udit, and thank you Pieter.

Comment: It's my Pleasure. Glad that it helped :)